# Why does the "rat" cant go through TOP and BOTTOM walls but can go through LEFT and RIGHT?

Tags: python, pygame

Im working on a pygame ASCII roguelike and i have my first "enemy" there. Its a rat, but i have a problem where the rat can walk through the LEFT and RIGHT wall but cant go through the UPPER and BOTTOM wall.

i tried nothing and i ran out of ideas

```
ratUP = pygame.Rect(enemypos.ratposx, enemypos.ratposy-16, 16, 16)
ratDOWN = pygame.Rect(enemypos.ratposx, enemypos.ratposy+16, 16, 16)
ratRIGHT = pygame.Rect(enemypos.ratposx-16, enemypos.ratposy, 16, 16)
ratLEFT = pygame.Rect(enemypos.ratposx+16, enemypos.ratposy, 16, 16)

pygame.draw.rect(win, white, ratUP)
pygame.draw.rect(win, white, ratDOWN)
pygame.draw.rect(win, white, ratLEFT)
pygame.draw.rect(win, white, ratRIGHT)


if keys[pygame.K_w] or keys[pygame.K_s] or keys[pygame.K_a] or keys[pygame.K_d]:
    if emovement == 1:
        if ratUP.colliderect(WRectTOP):
            print("rat had hit the wall")
        else:
            enemypos.ratposy -= ratvel
    if emovement == 2:
        if ratDOWN.colliderect(WRectBOT):
            print("rat had hit the wall")
        else:
            enemypos.ratposy += ratvel
    if emovement == 3:
        if ratLEFT.colliderect(WRectLEFT):
            print("rat had hit the wall")
        else: 
            enemypos.ratposx -= ratvel
    if emovement == 4:
        if ratRIGHT.colliderect(WRectRIGHT):
            print("rat had hit the wall")
        else:
            enemypos.ratposx += ratvel
```

I want the rat to be stopped at any wall.

Comment: what is the value for ratvel? I'm wondering whether the velocity is too large and thus it skips over the bounding box for the rectangle.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com./help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Comment: As @mattsap pointed out, if ratvel carries the rat through and entirely beyond the wall, colliderect will return `False`.  If this is the case, either take smaller steps, or check that the rat is still within the positional boundaries.  One way to do that is declare the entire field, minus the rat's size, to be a rectangle -- the rat *must* "collide" with that to be legally in the playing area.

Comment: An additional method to @Prune may to do line intersection detection, rather than the built-in method (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-two-given-line-segments-intersect/) . You could treat the wall as a line and check if it intersects with the line made by the rats position to the rats next position if moved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've swapped left and right. Left is the negative x direction and right the positive x direction. So `ratRIGHT` and `ratLEFT` are wrong.

It has to be:

<s>`ratRIGHT = pygame.Rect(enemypos.ratposx-16, enemypos.ratposy, 16, 16)`</s>
<s>`ratLEFT  = pygame.Rect(enemypos.ratposx+16, enemypos.ratposy, 16, 16)`</s>

```py
ratLEFT  = pygame.Rect(enemypos.ratposx-16, enemypos.ratposy, 16, 16)
ratRIGHT = pygame.Rect(enemypos.ratposx+16, enemypos.ratposy, 16, 16)
```